# What would be the best way to let a user change his password? (with Rails API and has_secure_password)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, passwords

I'm currently building a small website for a friend, and I want him to be able to change his password, since the one he'll get is seeded and visible from the Git repository (don't worry, he's well aware this is the first thing he'll have to change)

I'm used to Ruby on Rails in general, but this is the first time for me that I use an API instead of the "standard" version of Rails, and I'm not used at all with everything about tokens and such.

In the back-office where he can change some elements from the website, I made a specific page where he can change some details such as his biography, his profile picture, his social networks links, etc etc. On this page, I added a part where he can change his password, with the fields `current_password`, `password` and `password_confirmation`. I also started to setup some verifications, but the thing is that if I type 3 times "password" in the fields, I'll get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid | Validation failed: password can't be blank

What troubles me are two elements: the first one is that the error is not returned as JSON, but as HTML (this is my first question, how can I force the format to JSON?), and I made sure that the passwords were sent to the API (front is VueJS, but this is not the problem), but it still shows up the error.

Here is my code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
# ...
wrap_parameters :user, include: %i[password password_confirmatioon current_password]
# ...

def profile
  if @user.update(user_params)
    render json: @user, status: :ok
  else
    render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  @user.reset_password!(user_params[:new_password])
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  mount_base64_uploader :picture, BioFaceUploader
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  has_secure_password

  attr_accessor :old_password
  attr_accessor :profile

  def generate_password_token!
    begin
      self.reset_password_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(reset_password_token: reset_password_token)
    self.reset_password_token_expires_at = 1.day.from_now
    save!
  end

  def reset_password!(password)
    self.reset_password_token = nil
    self.password = password
    save!
  end

  def clear_password_token!
    self.reset_password_token = nil
    self.reset_password_token_expires_at = nil
    save!
  end
end
```

** edit: this is the server log input when I try to POST the new password**

```
Started POST "/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-21 13:15:33 +0200
Processing by UsersController#profile as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>1, "email"=>"email@email.me", "password_digest"=>"[FILTERED]", [some more unrelated datas], "created_at"=>"2018-09-17T11:38:27.464Z", "updated_at"=>"2018-09-21T10:23:50.233Z", "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "reset_password_token_expires_at"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:39
Unpermitted parameters: :password, :current_password
Unpermitted parameters: :password, :current_password
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27
Unpermitted parameters: :password, :current_password
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:21
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:21
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

As you can see, 2 fields were unauthorized, I added them to the allowed parameters, but now I have the following error:

> Unknown attribute 'current_password' for User

Should I add it to the `attr_accessor`'s list?

What should I do to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you update the question with the server log that appears when the form is submitted?

Comment: on side not `password_confirmatioon` spelling is wrong, are you passing correct params?

Comment: Hello, I'll update my question with the server log output whenever I can, it should be in a couple hours, thanks!

Comment: Updated my question, sorry for the time it took